# Which book help us to do the best EDA for data science?

Tags: machine-learning, references

I am new at data science. I would like to make ML models in orde to make predictions, but I am lost when I have to make interpretations to data... I would really like to understand the data with statistical analysis in order to chose a ML algorithm

Is there any book that teach all this stuff or something I am not considering?